# Android Bottom navigation bar animation

Tags: android, animation

[image: How can I create animation like below GIF for android bottom navigation bar. I want to create same animation for iOS also. I checked many github project but I didn't get success to create same animation. I don't know the exact animation name.]

How can I create animation like below GIF for android bottom navigation bar. I want to create same animation for iOS also. I checked many github project but I didn't get success to create same animation. I don't know the exact animation name.

Answer (score 1):

Check the video demo, i created by creating the custom tab indicator in Jetpack compose, you can also use below code snippet to create same animation in IOS by using Compose for IOS.

[Video Demo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yybio-GwH4E59urw3x48s3J4QRl9MOw4/view?usp=sharing)

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun NavigationScreen() {
    val tabsList = mutableListOf("Profile", "Photos", "Add", "Notification", "Cart")
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState()

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        HorizontalPager(
            state = pagerState, modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(bottom = 100.dp),
            pageCount = tabsList.size
        ) {
            when (it) {
                0 -> Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                    Text(text = "Hello 0", modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center))
                }

                1 -> Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                    Text(text = "Hello 1", modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center))
                }

                2 -> Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                    Text(text = "Hello 2", modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center))
                }

                3 -> Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                    Text(text = "Hello 3", modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center))
                }

                4 -> Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                    Text(text = "Hello 4", modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center))
                }
            }
        }
        CustomTabs(
            tabsList,
            pagerState,
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.BottomStart)
                .fillMaxWidth()
        )
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun CustomTabs(
    tabsList: MutableList<String>,
    pagerState: PagerState,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    TabRow(modifier = modifier,
        selectedTabIndex = pagerState.currentPage,
        indicator = {
            CustomTabIndicator(it, pagerState)
        },
        tabs = {
            tabsList.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
                val painterSrc = remember {
                    when (index) {
                        0 -> R.drawable.ic_profile
                        1 -> R.drawable.ic_gallery
                        2 -> R.drawable.ic_add
                        3 -> R.drawable.ic_notification
                        4 -> R.drawable.ic_cart
                        else -> R.drawable.ic_profile
                    }

                }


                Tab(modifier = Modifier.zIndex(6f),
                    selected = pagerState.currentPage == index,
                    onClick = { /* TODO */ },
                    icon = {
                        Image(
                            painter = painterResource(painterSrc),
                            contentDescription = null,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .size(60.dp)
                                .clip(CircleShape)
                        )
                    })
            }
        },
        divider = {
            TabRowDefaults.Indicator(
                height = 0.dp, color = Color.Transparent
            )
        })

}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun CustomTabIndicator(tabPositions: List<TabPosition>, pagerState: PagerState) {
    val transition = updateTransition(pagerState.currentPage)
    val indicatorStart by transition.animateDp(
        transitionSpec = {
            if (initialState < targetState) {
                spring(dampingRatio = 1f, stiffness = 50f)
            } else {
                spring(dampingRatio = 1f, stiffness = 1000f)
            }
        }, label = ""
    ) {
        tabPositions[it].left
    }

    val indicatorEnd by transition.animateDp(
        transitionSpec = {
            if (initialState < targetState) {
                spring(dampingRatio = 1f, stiffness = 1000f)
            } else {
                spring(dampingRatio = 1f, stiffness = 50f)
            }
        }, label = ""
    ) {
        tabPositions[it].right
    }

    val color = when (pagerState.currentPage) {
        1 -> {
            Color(0xFF6789AC)
        }

        2 -> {
            Color(0xFF71A889)
        }

        else -> {
            Color.Transparent
        }
    }

    Box(
        Modifier
            .offset(x = indicatorStart)
            .wrapContentSize(align = Alignment.BottomStart)
            .width(indicatorEnd - indicatorStart)
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(color = color, CircleShape)
            .zIndex(1f)
    )
}
```